# Storing user inputted data to text file

Tags: user-input, saving-data

so I have the following code (not mine but, I wise to modify it):

```
def main(): 
outfile = open("data.txt","w")
fname = input("Please enter your first name:")
lname = input("Please enter your last name: ")
outfile.write(fname)
outfile.write("\t")
outfile.write(lname)
outfile.close()
main()
```

What I need it to do is, is for it to save the text to a .txt file (which, it already does) however, when I re-run the code, it overwrites what is saved in the .txt file. As opposed to overwriting, I need it to save each re-run of the code.

I am thinking that I need two solutions here

(i): Using some kind of loop

(ii): Appending something

I am using a MacBook and I run my codes from the terminal. Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current timestamp and append it with the filename. That will resolve your problem

e.g.

```
filename="data_{}.txt".format(datetime.datetime.now())
outfile = open(filename,"w")
```

Note.
you have to import datetime library
e.g.

```
import datetime
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fakhar, 

I've put in the following:

import datetime
def main():

  filename = "data" + datetime.datetime.now() +".txt"
  outfile = open(filename,"w")
  fname = input("Please enter your first name: ")
  lname = input("Please enter your last name: ")
  outfile.write(fname)
  outfile.write("\t")
  outfile.write(lname)
  outfile.close()
main()

But I am now getting the error 'can only concatenate stir (not "data time.datetime"). What do I need to do?

Comment: It’s the string concatenation issue. My bad I forgot to use python concatenation. Use this line filename="data_{}.txt".format(datetime.datetime.now()) . It will resolve the string concatenation issue

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it